# phpstorm7 keyboard shortcut to create an opening curly brace

Tags: phpstorm

After many hours of research I haven't found if exist a keyboard shortcut for create an opening curly brace `{` or if exists a way to create this type of shortcut.

**EDIT:**
I have an Italian keyboard layout and not EU as I wrote in my comment.

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/configuring-keyboard-shortcuts.html#d853446e377 But this doesn’t make a lot of sense, I think. I am not sure if you can create a keyboard shortcut for just a simple key, most likely you will have to use a least one of `ctrl` or `alt` I’d assume – and with that, there would be little to no gain.

Comment: If you want this for programming, where curly braces are needed frequently, then I’d suggest you either switch to US keyboard layout (if you’re not using that already), or create your own keyboard layout – for Windows, Microsoft offers a tool for that, called _Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator_.

Comment: A Keyboard shortcut to create `{` ? Have you tried **Shift+[** ?

Comment: @CBroe Tx! I will follow your link and if the case also the tip about the Microsoft tool (I have an EU keyboard and maybe is more simpler then create a custom shortcut). @LazyOne Shift+[ obviously give me a pair of square braces... I need only the opening `{`

Comment: *"Shift+[ obviously give me a pair of square braces"* What's your keyboard layout? Because it's a standard key combination for `{` and word "obviously" is not appropriate here. As for "pair" -- this behaviour can be turned off in `Settings | Editor | Smart Keys --> Insert pair XXX`

Comment: @LazyOne I'm sorry I did not want to be offensive (English is not my native language). I have an Italian layout and not EU as I said in my previous comment (my mistake).

Comment: @gp_sflover No worries -- you were not offensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the tips of @CBroe and @LazyOne (*about keyboard layout*) the shortcut for the Italian Keyboard Layout is: `AltGr + Shift + [`